# Counting non-overlapping substrings of size 2 and 3 in a string

Tags: combinatorics

Given a string S of length n that contains exactly $\lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil $ b's and $\lfloor \frac{3n}{4} \rfloor$ a's:

Part 1: How many NON-overlapping occurrences of aa must occur in S? For e.g. in aaab... the aaa is counted as 1 non-overlapping occurrence of aa.

Part 2: If I "charge" 2 for each non-overlapping occurrence of aaa, and I "charge" 1 for each non-overlapping occurrence of aa, what is the minimum price that I will get for any such string S? For e.g. the price of aaaa is 2 while the price of 5 a's: aaaaa is 3.

Comment: Part $2$ isn't quite clear. From your example aaaa, it seems that the occurrences of aa and aaa must be non-overlapping not only among occurrences of the same substring, but also across occurrences of aa and aaa. If so, the price becomes dependent on choices. Is "minimum" to be interpreted as minimizing over all possible sets of choices, i.e. the buyer may successively select occurrences of either substring to pay for, until no more occurrences of either substring remain that do not overlap at least one occurrence of either substring already paid for?

Comment: I just realized that this interpretation doesn't fit with the minimum price of $3$ for aaaaa. In what sense is that a "minimum price" when the buyer could have paid for two non-overlapping occurrences of aa instead?

Comment: Given a particular string, the seller will charge as much as possible -- the buyer does not have a choice to select fewer occurrences. By minimum, I meant: over all possible strings of this type, you cannot find a string for which the seller will charge less.

Comment: That usage of "minimum" makes sense in the penultimate sentence, but it doesn't make sense in the last sentence, where you're talking about individual strings. If this was the intended meaning of "minimum", shouldn't it just say "price" then in the last sentence?

Comment: You are correct. Each string will have (in a sense the maximal) price. I want to "buy" the cheapest string (of which there may be many of course).

Comment: This can be thought of: how do I place the b's in the way that minimizes the overall price? The cheapest string that I could come up with is placing a b every 5th symbol (and using the extra 1/4-1/5 as well), yielding price 2n/5 - n/20.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest string I found would be to place a 'b' every other symbol in the beginning. This results in $1/4$ a's not being charged at all. This yields the first $n/2$ characters as a repetition of $(ab)^{n/4}$ followed by $a^{n/2}$. Paying 2 for every 3 of the second half of the string yields $n/2 \times 2/3 = n/3$.